# React Native- dev server returned 500

Tags: android, react-native

am trying to connect the react component with my native android app(Time being am experimenting with hello world project ) but its failing with following error. Any help would be appreciated.

Pkg.json config

"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
  "react-native": "^0.44.0",

StackTrace

bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `react/lib/ReactPropTypes` from `/Users/myMac/Documents/Androidapps/TestReactNative/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/Image.android.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:

Comment: I'm getting this too. Did you happen to figure it out and remember how?

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

npm install react@16.0.0-alpha.6 --save

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrade the RN 0.43 to 0.44. I removed node_modules folder and run the commands: npm install && npm install react@16.0.0-alpha.6 --save The commands resolved my issue. My package.json maybe help for you:

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "^0.44.0",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-image-capinsets": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-localization": "^0.1.30",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.1.8",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^1.1.2",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.9"
  },

Comment: Failing - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/ws/WebSocketListener;